How to transform this problem into a convex problem
We have the following optimisation problem:
\begin{align}\label{P1}
    \underset{\mathbf{A,B,C,D,}\boldsymbol{\Theta }}{\mathrm{min}} &\quad f(\mathbf{A})\\
    &\text{s.t.} \left[ \begin{matrix}
 \mathbf{A}&  \mathbf{B}&  \mathbf{E\Theta F}\\
 \mathbf{B}^H&  \mathbf{C}&  \mathbf{D}\\
 \left( \mathbf{E\Theta F} \right) ^H&  \mathbf{D}^H&  \mathbf{I}\\
\end{matrix} \right] \succeq \mathbf{0}.\\
&\mathbf{\Theta }=\mathbf{I}_{K}\otimes \boldsymbol{\alpha }=\left[ \begin{matrix}
 \boldsymbol{\alpha }^T&  0_{1\times L}&  0_{1\times L}&  \cdots&  0_{1\times L}\\
 0_{1\times L}&  \boldsymbol{\alpha }^T&  0_{1\times L}&  \cdots&  0_{1\times L}\\
 \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots&  \cdots\\
 0_{1\times L}&  0_{1\times L}&  0_{1\times L}&  \cdots&  \boldsymbol{\alpha }^T\\
\end{matrix} \right] ^T\in \mathbb{C} ^{KL\times K},   \\
&\boldsymbol{\alpha }=[e^{j\alpha _1},e^{j\alpha _2},\cdots ,e^{j\alpha _L}]^T,\alpha _l\in \left[ 0,2\pi \right) .
\end{align}
where $\otimes$ is kronecker product and $f(\mathbf{A})$ is convex functions respect to $\mathbf{A}$. Besides,matrix $\mathbf{E,F}$ and constant $K$,$L$ are given.
Clearly the first constraint is an LMI(linear matrix inequality) constraint for $\mathbf{A,B,C,D,}\boldsymbol{\Theta }$. The problem I'm having more trouble with is the mode one constraint on $\boldsymbol{\alpha }$. Of course we can convert it using SDR etc. But then the positive definite constraints about $\mathbf{\Theta}$ is not well handled after that.
I'm hoping to get some direction that I can carry on with.
